# 'NoneType' object is not iterable...Nominatim geocoding

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoder, geopandas, folium, nominatim

I am supposed to plot maps using Folium.I just have a csv file where one column is location.I am trying to get latitude and longitude for the given column containing thousands of value of places in a given district.Below is the code i am getting error as "  'NoneType' object is not iterable "

```
from geopandas.tools import geocode
for i in df['Location']:
   #if Nan:
   time.sleep(1)
   info = geocode(i,provider="nominatim")
```

Comment: How did you define `df`? There's likely an issue with a code preceding this.

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.